# Videos app makes the system crash after trying to play a video - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, video-player

It's been some months since I'm facing this issue. Everytime I try to play a video with any extension with the Videos app, the system freezes and I have to force the PC to power off and boot. This is what it looks like after opening it by default:
[image]

Has anyone faced this issue before? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: HW info

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 5.15.0-43-generic
- Shell: bash 5.1.16
- Resolution: 1920x1080
- DE: GNOME
- CPU: Intel i5-3450 (4) @ 3.500GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
- Memory: 3557MiB / 11933MiB

I have all media codecs installed, it was the first thing that I came up with facing this issue.

EDIT 2: opening the video with any other program (like VLC) works fine.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post hardware specification, particularly the graphics, and what formats are you trying to reproduce and whether you have installed appropriate codecs.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. Now, does it happen with both graphics or only Nvidia? Do you have the Nvidia drivers installed (and Secure Boot disabled)?

Comment: On both, having the latest driver installed. I also have secure boot disabled.

Comment: Then it musty be some weird codec that VLC (and very likely Kodi) because it works with its own sets of codecs, doesn't rely on system wide installed codecs, supports that one. That being the cased it may happen as well in Windows, VLC working but not others.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like graphics card issue.

If you are using vlc for playing videos go to Tools > Preferences > Video and then change Output to X11 video output (XCB).